# Proof of an equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-writing

If $$\sqrt{a-x} + \sqrt{b-x} + \sqrt{c-x} = 0$$ then prove that $$(a+b+c+3x)(a+b+c-x) = 4(ab+bc+ca).$$ Any hint to solve this problem is appreciated.

Comment: In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, please change your question title to make it more descriptive, there are a **lot** of questions about proofs of equations.

Comment: What are a,b,c,x?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Square roots are $\geqslant 0$ by definition, so for the initial sum to be zero you have all the three roots $=0$. So $a=x$, $b=x$ and $c=x$. The second equality turns out to be $(6x)(2x)=4(x^2+x^2+x^2)$.

Answer (score 2):

If $a,b,c,x \in \mathbb{R}$, then it is easy to find out that $a=b=c=x$ so the last equation is obviously satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

Why shall we assume something when we can prove the proposition directly.

Squaring  $\sqrt{a-x}+\sqrt{b-x}=-\sqrt{c-x}$ we get $$a+b-2x+2\sqrt{(a-x)(b-x)}=c-x$$

$$\iff2\sqrt{(a-x)(b-x)}=x-(a+b-c)$$

Squaring  we get $$4(a-x)(b-x)=x^2-2(a+b-c)x+(a+b-c)^2$$

$$\iff3x^2-2(a+b+c)x=(a+b-c)^2-4ab=(a+b+c)^2-4(ab+bc+ca)$$

$$\iff(a+b+c)^2+2x(a+b+c)-3x^2=4(ab+bc+ca)$$

Can you take it from here?